docker desktop encountered an unexpected error and needs to close
Docker desktop was working until I updated it (saw an update button in the app and updated it). After updating, a restart of the app happened and docker is refusing to connect again.
I uninstalled the application and installed it again but the problem persists.


Please share what type of machine/operating system (Windows, Mac, Linux)?

A Docker bug report might be more productive.  This error doesn't seem like anything in your own code, and if you're seeing it just from upgrading the Desktop application, it's unlikely the community can help resolve it.

It worked after I restarted my computer

I am having the same error. It's not the first time errors happen with Docker for Windows after update. It should teach me something by this time...
UPD: I reinstalled Docker and it solved the issue.

I did though, but it did not solve it. I restarted my machine and it worked. Thanks for the help
